# Search another file and add a value to certain field

Tags: linux, awk

File A:

```
Castro  2
Manuel  5
Daniela 8
...
```

File B:

```
Tom//UK  No
Mark//UK No
Castro//Chile Yes
...
Manuel//Spain No
```

Output:

```
Castro 2 Yes
Manuel 5 No
...
```

Enumerate every name in File A and search it in File B, and get the second field to add to field 3 of File A.

What I was trying:

`` cat File_A.txt | awk -F '\t' '{ print $1 }; $3=`grep -i $2 File_B.txt | head -1 | cut -f2`' ``

Answer (score 1):

**`Awk`** solution:

```
awk 'NR == FNR{ names[$1] = $2; next }
     { name = substr($1, 1, index($1, "/") - 1) }
     name in names { print name, names[name], $NF }' file1 file2
```

The output:

```
Castro 2 Yes
Manuel 5 No
```

Answer (score 0):

Another `awk` solution:

```
awk -F'//| ' 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$3;next}NR>FNR{print $0,a[$1]}' fileB fileA
```

Note that if fileB doesn't contain a name that is present in fileA, the line will be printed.